# setChildIndex On overlapping buttons

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two buttons on stage, on on top of each other. Im trying to use the setChildindex so that when I press the on button the off button will appear on top of it. and vise versa. But I keep getting this error, which i cant seem to understand.

Track On
    ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
    at com.audio::Sequencer/trackOn1()

```
private var trackOnOff:Boolean = true;

this.track1.trackOn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trackOn1);
this.track1.trackOff1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trackOff1);

public function trackOn1(event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
trace("Track On")
this.setChildIndex(this.track1.trackOff1, this.numChildren - 1);
trackOnOff = true;
}

public function trackOff1(event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
trace("Track Off")
this.setChildIndex(this.track1.trackOn1, this.numChildren - 1);
trackOnOff = false;
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your `track1` to be a MovieClip with assets on it, namely `trackOff1`, `trackOn1`. If so, You have to target your `setChildIndex()` call to that MC instead of `this`.

```
public function trackOn1(event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    trace("Track On")
    this.track1.setChildIndex(this.track1.trackOff1, this.track1.numChildren - 1);
    trackOnOff = true;
}

public function trackOff1(event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    trace("Track Off")
    this.track1.setChildIndex(this.track1.trackOn1, this.track1.numChildren - 1);
    trackOnOff = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple methods to do this:

`swapChildren(track1, track2);`

Both buttons could call this one function and it would have the same effect as using setChildIndex to swap them around, alternatively simply calling `addChild(track1)` or `addChild(track2)` brings the movieclip in front of anything else in the same layer.